# Configurar el acceso externo de MySql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

He realizado la instalación de Mysql con `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`. Por ssh sí que puedo entrar pero por navicat no me deja.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar con la configuración de Mysql? porque realizo todo lo que creo que es necesario, pero por ssh sí conecto pero no por navicat (por ejemplo).

Comment: ¿Qué problema tienes exactamente? ¿Podrías describirlo o facilitarnos más información para ayudarte?

Comment: Pues realizo la instalación de Mysql con `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`, por ssh si que puedo entrar pero por navicat no me deja

Comment: Vale, no tenía ni idea de lo que es navicat.  Esto no está relacionado ni con nginx ni con php 7.2, está relacionado con MySQL. Por favor, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/230368/edit) y cambia el asunto y el contenido de la pregunta para que hable sobre el problema de querer conectarte con navicat para administrar tu mysql de manera remota. Gracias.

Comment: Bueno yo creo que si tiene que ver algo, dado que la instalación se a hecho en un servidor ubuntu con nginx

Comment: Piensa en cómo vemos nosotros, como colaboradores, el listado de problemas de stackoverflow si vemos un asunto que pone "Servidor Ubuntu con nginx y php 7.2"... en ningún lado se habla de querer usar navicat para acceder a un mysql remoto, por lo que es probable que la gente experta en MySQL ni tan siquiera abra tu pregunta para leerla. Estás limitando la ayuda que te podemos ofrecer.

Comment: ¿Podrías teclear esto en tu cliente de SSH y decirme qué te devuelve? `grep -R "bind-address" /etc/mysql/`

Comment: 127.0.0.1   - también la cambie creo recordar por 0.0.0.0 pero tampoco

Comment: El soporte me va a llevar unas preguntas más, es mejor que [continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88394/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-miguel).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para configurar el acceso externo a tu servidor MySQL debes seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. Hacer que el servidor MySQL escuche conexiones externas (y no sólo desde `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`).
2. Habilitar el acceso al servidor MySQL en el firewall.
3. Crear el usuario `root` remoto y darle privilegios.

A continuación paso a detallar cada uno de los pasos.

#### Hacer que el servidor MySQL escuche conexiones externas

Hay que editar el archivo `my.cnf` para cambiar `bind-address` a `0.0.0.0`.

En este caso particular el archivo estaba localizado en `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`.

#### Habilitar el acceso al servidor MySQL en el firewall

Como se estaba usando como firewall `ufw`, hay que activar el acceso al puerto 3306 usado por el servidor MySQL tecleando:

```
# ufw allow 3306
```

#### Crear el usuario `root` remoto y darle privilegios

Para crear un usuario `root` remoto deben usarse las siguientes consultas SQL:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'tu_clave_de_root';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'tu_clave_de_root';
```

Si el usuario `'root'@'%'` ya existe, pero se desconoce la contraseña, se puede cambiar usando:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'tu_clave_de_root';
```

Comment: creo que deberias cambiar el titulo a esta pregunta, el problema no es navicat es configuracion del servicio , puede ser muy util para otras personas, ya lo modifique pero creo que puede mejorar

Comment: Perfecto. Sugerí ese cambio en un principio para que fuera más descriptivo y se acercara más al problema real que estaba sufriendo. El asunto inicial no tan siquiera hacía referencia a MySQL.